# не получается задать css selector BeautifulSoup (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Нужно по заданной категории на Flickr загрузить все найденные изображения на жесткий диск. Не получается разобраться с конструкцией CSS селектора

```
import requests, bs4

res = requests.get('https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=cats')
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="html.parser")
flickrElem = soup.select('.interaction-view')
print(flickrElem)
```

вот в таком варианте кода, он находит все div. Но ссылки хранятся в тэге a во вложенном div. И по идеи CSS селектор должен иметь вид

```
flickrElem = soup.select('.interaction-view div a')
```

но при этом список получается пустым

Comment: Отключил выполнение javascript через инспектор браузера, на странице нет тегов по тому пути, но картинки, кст, остались. Вам или парсить то, что есть, или использовать парсер с движком на javascript (типа селениума)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключил выполнение javascript через инспектор браузера, на странице нет тегов по тому пути, но картинки, кст, остались. Вам или парсить то, что есть (**сделаю пример по этому варианту**), или использовать парсер с движком на javascript (типа [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium))

Парсер `bs4` не умеет работать с javascript'ом, поэтому отключив его на странице мы сможешь увидеть страницу, которую и пытаемся парсить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ней есть ссылки на превью картинок, скрытые в атрибуте `style`. Чтобы извлечь его нужно:

- Перебирать элементы с атрибутом `style`
- Из атрибута `style` искать ссылки на картинки (`re.search`)
- Из относительной ссылки сделать абсолютную (`urljoin`)

Пример:

```
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


rs = requests.get('https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=cats')
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

for x in root.select('.view.photo-list-photo-view[style]'):
    m = re.search(r'url\((.+?)\)', x['style'])
    url_img = urljoin(rs.url, m.group(1))
    print(url_img)
```

Результат:

```
https://live.staticflickr.com/5598/14934282524_344c84246b_n.jpg
https://live.staticflickr.com/4838/45925416992_c9caac8cb9_m.jpg
https://live.staticflickr.com/4536/38465451442_59291a4a2f_n.jpg
...
https://live.staticflickr.com/267/31671889412_bb37b917be_n.jpg
https://live.staticflickr.com/70/175237265_029f7974a2_w.jpg
https://live.staticflickr.com/3488/4051998735_5b4863ac11_m.jpg
https://live.staticflickr.com/5036/5881933297_7974eaff82_n.jpg
```